# $nearSphere dosnot work as expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection pets where i store animals with location on that collection i have index

```
{
    "Cache.Location" : "2dsphere"
}
```

So when i am run query i expect to get elements which are near my city lviv in max distance 100 KM

```
db.Pet.find({ "Cache.Location" : { "$nearSphere" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [24.029717000000005, 49.839683] } }, "$maxDistance" : 100000.0 } })
```

But it returns strange results like pets from Russia and Israel.

But i have many pets in my location which should be returned

```
{
    "_id" : 336,
    "PetTypeId" : 1,
    "UserId" : 373,
    "PetBreedId" : 127,
    "Adverts" : [],
    "Name" : "Каспер",
    "Birthdate" : ISODate("2009-04-06T21:00:00.000Z"),
    "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2011-07-27T18:32:25.000Z"),
    "MainImageFileId" : 1361,
    "Description" : "",
    "Sex" : 1,
    "Cache" : {
        "MainImage" : "http://img.thebestofpets.com/%size%/1/1361.jpg",
        "Location" : {

            "lat" : 49.83968353271484, "lng" : 24.02971649169922
        }
    }
}
```

So what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more than 4 hours i went to bed and just in the morning i got what was wrong.

If you pay attention to location you will see

```
"Location" : {

            "lat" : 49.83968353271484, "lng" : 24.02971649169922
        }
```

Latitude is going first but everywhere in mongodb documentation it says that it should be second field.

so i just fix my entity to look like

using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

```
namespace Pets.Domain.Entity
{
    public class Location
    {
        public Location()
        {

        }
        public Location(double lat, double lon)
        {
            Latitude = lat;
            Langtitude = lon;
        }
        [BsonElement("lat", Order = 2)]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("lng", Order = 1)]
        public double Langtitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and now it works as expection

PS. Mongo is so cool :)